# When is Fermi golden rule exact?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

My recent study [Nonsmooth and level-resolved dynamics illustrated with a periodically driven tight binding model](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4280)
motivates me to ask this question:

Is there any example in which the [Fermi golden rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) gives a quantitatively exact prediction of the transition rate?

Note that the Fermi golden rule is just a first order perturbation result. In a generic problem, it should not be exact. I mean, the transition probability $p(t)$ should be a linear function of time for $t_{c1} <t < t_{c2}$, where $t_{c1}$ and $t_{c2}$ are two characteristic times, but the slope is not that predicted by Fermi golden rule.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1766/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I couldn't stop myself from [googling that](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22and+links+therein.+%E2%80%93+Qmechanic%22+site%3Aphysics.stackexchange.com). You should get a badge when you get to 1k!

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty: Ha-ha.

Comment: Are you willing to accept answers about when first-order time-dependent perturbation theory is exact? It seems very unlikely to me that Fermi's golden rule, by which I mean the $t\to\infty$ limit of first-order perturbation theory, is ever exact for all times. If you measure a system very quickly after applying a perturbation I wouldn't expect the energy expectation value  with respect to the bare Hamiltonian of the initial and final states to be the same.